# Setting nocache but still caching

Tags: php, caching

I'm using `session_cache_limiter('nocache')` on my page that I don't want cached, but it's still caching.

Anything I have forgotten?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're setting this before any output is set?

Comment: Yes, at the very top, and before session_start();

Comment: Have you looked at the headers to make sure they're being sent properly? Developer tools should be able to tell you that

Comment: I'm still able to return to the previous page after loggout out.
Is there anything the could overrule the session_cache_limiter('nocache')?

Answer (score -1):

try

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() - 24 * 3600).' GMT');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: That's what [session_cache_limiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php) does